# Turning off "Update page numbers only" in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

When I update the fields document-wide (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>F9</kbd>) in a Word document that has a table of contents, a dialog appears asking if I want to update page numbers only, or update the entire table. I never want to update page numbers only if the document headings have changed, nor will I ever.

(Apparently this is given as an option in case someone has manually changed an automatically generated ToC, which is almost always a really bad idea.)

Unfortunately, "Update page numbers only" is the default selection in the dialog, which means that I have to select the other option every time. I update the fields all the time when I'm working in a document that has figures and cross-references, so this is an annoying extra step I'd really like to get rid of.

Is there any way to tell Word to stop asking me this stupid unnecessary question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using macros. Record a macro only for the "Update entire table" option (you can assign the macro to a button and save it in the Quick Access Toolbar)

Update: How to record a macro (assuming you already have the TOC added in the document)

You must have the Developer tab displayed in the ribbon (if not go to *Word Options* select the *Popular* tab and tick the *Show Developer tab in the Ribbon*)

Select Record Macro, type a name for the macro and assign it to a button:

[image]

The Customize tab in *Word Option* should pop up and you can add your macro button to Quick Access Ribbon:

[image]

Now open the *References* tab, click the *Update table* option  and select *Update entire table*, and then press OK. You can stop the recording - go back to *Developer* tab press the *Stop Recording* button:

[image]

Now,  every time you want to update the entire table of content just press the button from the Quick Access Toolbar.

Comment: Any update on this for Word 2013? Maybe there is a built-in option now?

Comment: No, it is the same behavior in Word 2013.

Comment: This might update the table, but when doing  (Ctrl+A, F9) wouldn't that still prompt the same question as it's not making use of the macro?  This doesn't seem to get rid of the extra manual click the question seems to be trying to get rid of.